# How to add a new field to existing data in the json document?

Tags: json, api, go

I am a beginner in Golang..I have created an API which is reading the data from couchbase well but I am not able to write new fields in the json document..The code of writing new data is below:

```
func appendDataEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter,req *http.Request){
    var data map[string]interface{}
    _ = json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&data)
    fmt.Println(data)
    params := mux.Vars(req)
    str := params["id"]

    message := message{ Student :data["student"].([]struct),//Here is another problem.How to write type of Student since it is referring to another structure."struct" is throwing type error.
                        College :data["college"].(string),
                        CollegeId: data["collegeid"].(string),
                        Hobbies :data["hobbies"].([]string),
                        Firstname: data["firstname"].(string),
                        Address: data["address"].(string),//New field to be inserted
                        Mobile: data["mobile"].(string),//New field to be inserted
    }
    fmt.Println(message.Address)
    _,err:=bucket.Insert(str, message, 0)

    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Println("Error in inserting")
        w.WriteHeader(401)
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(message)
}
```

Still having problems.Now the updated code snippet is:

```
    message:=message{
    Student :data["student"].([]Student),//Error still exists here
    College :data["college"].(string),
    CollegeId :data["collegeid"].(string),
    Hobbies :data["hobbies"].([]string),
    Firstname :data["firstname"].(string),
    Add: data["a"].(string),
    Mo: data["m"].(string),
    }
    _,err:=bucket.Insert(str, message, 0)
```

The error is:

```
    panic serving [::1]:63648: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not []main.Student
```

Comment: Structure is:

        type message struct{
       Student []details `json:"student,omitempty"`
       College string `json:"college,omitempty"`
       CollegeId string `json:"collegeid,omitempty"`
       Hobbies []string `json:"hobbies,omitempty"`
       Firstname string `json:"firstname,omitempty"`
       Address string `json:address,omitempty"`
       Mobile string `json:mobile,omiempty"`
       }

Comment: The fields "address" and "mobile" is not present currently in the document.The client is sending request to insert these new fields in the document.All other fields are already present in the document.How to do this???

Comment: Edit your post rather then providing information in the comment section. This way we can see your question in the broader sense.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to notice since the code you provided is not fully available (what about providing code for the `message` struct?):

When getting a request from the client, you unmarshal it into a `map[string]{}interface` object. From there, you construct manually a `message` object. Why don't you construct the `message` object without having to work with type assertions? You could try doing something like so:

```
type Message struct {
    Student []Student `json:"student"`
    College String `json:"college"`
    CollegeId String `json:"collegeid"`
    Hobbies []String `json:"hobbies"`
    FirstName String `json:"firstname"`
    Address String `json:"address"`
    Mobile String `json:"mobile"`
}

type Student struct {
    Name String `json:"name"`
    Qualifications []String `json:"qualifications"`
    Email String `json:"email"`
}

var data Message
if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

fmt.Println(data)
```

This would also take care of the `student` struct you were having difficulties with.

I would recommend reading [this article](https://eager.io/blog/go-and-json/) to get you started with JSON and Go.